# Cannot get new language support working on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: 14.10, language-support, input-language

I am running Ubuntu 14.10.

And at the moment I have got `Russian` and `English (UK)` installed on my computer. I installed them through `System Settings > Language Support`. But now I want to add Korean and that is where the problem has come up.

So I go into the `Language Support` settings and click `Install / Remove Languages...`, I then select `Korean` from the list and click `Apply Changes`. After the installation has finished I go into the `Text Entry` settings: [image: http://i.imgur.com/SuqHqFu.png]

And click the little `+` sign. Then I find and add `Korean` from the list (after I found that this did not work I tried all the other `Korean` options, but still did not work): [image: http://i.imgur.com/eZ23MEx.png]

But then when I select `Korean` as the language I want to type as, it still stays at English. And not matter what I do, I cannot seem to get any other languages working.

Why is this? And what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you try *Korean (Hangul)* instead.

*Edit:*

Seems to not be sufficient. So I downgraded to version 1.4.2-3 (the Trusty version) of the *ibus-hangul* package. Made a difference indeed.

얻얻언ㄹㅈ

(Hope that's Korean characters...)

*Edit II:*

It turned out that IBus Hangul works fine in 14.10 (and 15.04) as well. The thing is that they added a toggle, so it's not sufficient to select the Hangul engine, bug you also need to turn on "Hangul mode".

The bug report which was filed, and which is mentioned in the comments below, has rightly been closed as "invalid".

Comment: I tried that as well but it did not work. In fact I tried all of the Korean options.

Comment: @Toroidal: Hmm.. Doesn't work for me either. It used to work. Possibly a new bug. :(

Comment: I have reported it as a bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1412036 But I thought I should also ask in the forums just in case.

Comment: @Toroidal: Given the success when downgrading ibus-hangul (see my edited answer) I think this is a ibus-hangul bug. Don't think it's related to adding new input methods, neither has it anything to do with the xorg package.

Comment: Right, I have now moved it: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus-hangul/+bug/1412036

Comment: @Toroidal: Great! I added some stuff to the bug report.

Comment: Good, I hope that it gets fixed soon.